# Add value to firestore array even if value exists in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

I've been searching the web for an hour now and I cannot find a single way of adding an element to a firestore array even if it exists. I understand that `arrayUnion` will add a value to an array **but only if it does not already exist**.

I've tried reading the array from the db. Pushing an element to this new list. Adding it to a state. Writing this states value to the db, but I always get `null`.

```
const Home = () =>  {
    const [finalWpm,setFinalWpm] = useState(null)
    function myFunc(){return val}
    function onFinish() {
      if (condition) {
        //add new wpm entry to db under wpmHistory
        db.collection("users")
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
          setFinalWpm(doc.data().wpmHistory.push(myFunc()))
        })
        console.log(finalWpm)
      }
    }
```

output value

```
null
```

Is there another way of approaching this? Or what can I fix in my code to make it work.

Here is my full home page code

> http://pastie.org/p/6mz8uH50LoqdBRV67VICwO

Comment: The primary problem here is that you're misunderstanding how promises work in JS.  That should be the first thing to learn.  If you add more console logging at each stage, you'll begin to understand why things don't happen in the order you expect.

Answer (score -1):

I did end up figuring something out. I think a workaround to adding values to an array instead of ignoring these values would be to simply

Read the current array's state

Push a new value to this array

Update this new list to the db

**Read, Push Update**

In order to do this I used async/await

```
const Home = () =>  {
  async function onFinish() {
    if (text.length-1 === symbols) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      //call popup
      setPopup(true)
      setFinished(true)
      setStarted(false)
      //add new wpm entry to db under wpmHistorydb.collection("users").doc(userId).get().then(async (doc) => {
          const x = await doc.data().wpmHistory
          x.push(getFinalWpm(errors,symbols,sec))
          db.collection("users").doc(userId).update({wpmHistory: x})
      })
    }
  }
}
```

It looks quite messy as I've just learnt more about this technique, so feel free to change it up a bit.